# Doubt on transformation laws of tensors and spinors using standard tensor calculus and group theory

Tags: special-relativity, field-theory, tensor-calculus, representation-theory, spinors

### 1) Introduction

From standard tensor calculus, here restricted to Minkowski spacetime, we learned that:

> A scalar field is a object that transforms as:
>
> $$\phi'(x^{\mu'}) = \phi(x^{\mu})\tag{1}$$
> A vector field is a object that transforms as:
>
> $$A^{\mu'} = \Lambda^{\mu'}\hspace{0.2mm}_{\nu}A^{\nu}\tag{2}$$
> A covector field is a object that transforms as:
>
> $$A_{\mu'} = \Lambda^{\nu}\hspace{0.2mm}_{\mu'}A_{\nu}\tag{3}$$
> In general a tensor field of type $(p,q)$ transforms as:
> $$T^{\mu'_{1}...\mu'_{p}}\hspace{0.2mm}_{\nu'_{1}...\nu'_{q}} = \Lambda^{\mu'_{1}}\hspace{0.2mm}_{\alpha_{1}}\cdots\Lambda^{\mu'_{p}}\hspace{0.2mm}_{\alpha_{p}}\Lambda^{\beta_{1}}\hspace{0.2mm}_{\nu'_{1}}\cdots\Lambda^{\beta_{q}}\hspace{0.2mm}_{\nu'_{q}}T^{\alpha_{1}...\alpha_{p}}\hspace{0.2mm}_{\beta_{1}...\beta_{q}} \tag{4}$$

Now, in reference $[1]$, the author defines the tranformation law for Spinors:

> A spinor is a object that transforms as:
>
> $$\psi'_{r} = S(\Lambda)^{s}\hspace{0.2mm}_{r}\psi_{s}\tag{5}$$

It is all fine here, in my opinion. I mean, you have a set of transformation laws that defines a set of objects; also, you can even understand that phrase: "a spinor is like a vector", since the spinor have a index but the matrix transformation isn't just a Lorentz boost matrix (therefore this defines another type of object).

### 2) My question

The above transformation laws forms a very satisfying picture for me. But, my problem begins when in the same section of $[1]$, the author defines different transformation laws "based on representaitons of Lorentz group". My concern isn't about representantions or groups, rather, I'm struggling to understand why you should have different transformation laws based on group theory.
I will explain better.

So, my doubt begins when the author in $[1]$, states that a general field (a field forming a $K$-dimensional irreducible representation of the Lorentz group) transforms as (for infinitesimal transformations):

$$\phi'_{a}(x^{\mu'}) = S_{a}\hspace{0.2mm}^{b}\phi_{b}(x^{\mu}) = (\delta_{a}\hspace{0.2mm}^{b}+\frac{1}{2}\omega_{\alpha \beta}\Sigma_{a}^{\alpha \beta b})\phi_{b}(x^{\mu}) \tag{6}$$

Then he states that the transformation laws for scalar, vector and spinor fields occurs when:

> Scalar: $\Sigma^{\alpha \beta} = 0 \tag{7}$
>
> Vector: $\Sigma_{\xi \delta}^{\alpha \beta} = g^{\alpha }_{\xi}g^{\beta}_{\delta} - g^{\alpha}_{\delta}g^{\beta}_{\xi} \tag{8}$
>
> Spinor: $\Sigma_{r s}^{\alpha \beta} = \frac{i}{2}(\gamma^{\alpha} \gamma^{\beta} - \gamma^{\beta} \gamma^{\alpha})_{rs} \tag{9}$

So, clearly the transformation laws $(1)-(5)$ are very different from $(6)-(9)$. This confuses me because, from differential geometry a transformation law is something very strong and very well defined for all tensor fields: we really know that a transformation law suffices to define tensor fields in terms of charts. It seems that you can define different tranformation laws in group theory (even knowing that the theory of Lie Groups are just manifold theory).

It seems that when you use the transformation laws $(1) - (4)$ you classify the mathematical objects in terms of spacetime it self, and when you use the $(6) - (9)$ you classify vectors and so on, in terms of "spin space" (which would be something strange to conceive, since spinors are sections of spinor bundles $\mathcal{S}$ and tensors are sections of tensor bundles $\mathcal{T}^{p}_{q}$ $[2]$)

**So, my question is: why field theory use the transformation laws $(6) - (9)$ instead of $(1) - (4)$?** Or, in other words, what is happening between the transformation laws $(6) - (9)$ and $(1) - (4)$?

---

### References

$[1]$ Kerson Huang. *Quantum Field Theory: From Operators to Path Integrals*, $2004$, pages $46 - 48$.

$[2]$ Mark Hamiltion. *Mathematical Gauge Theory*, Springer.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but tensor fields in a smooth manifold also admit one group-theoretic presentation. They are defined in terms of representations of the general linear group ${\rm GL}(n,\mathbb{R})$ where $n=\dim M$ Is the dimension of the smooth manifold.

Comment: I know about that, and in fact this is a clear usage of group theory as you mentioned. But why text books on QFT use the transformations $(6)-(9)$ instead of $(1) - (4)$?

Comment: The equations (6) - (9) are really the infinitesimal versions. You can write Lorentz transformations as $\Lambda=\exp\left(\frac{i}{2}\omega_{\alpha\beta}{\cal J}^{\alpha\beta}\right)$. Then in a representation space you have generators $\Sigma^{\alpha\beta}$ which implements the commutation relations of the Lorentz algebra and the Lorentz transformation is $D(\Lambda)=\exp\left(\frac{i}{2}\omega_{\alpha\beta}\Sigma^{\alpha\beta}\right)$. Specifying the generators specifies the representation.

Comment: Start from the first set of equations, specialize to infinitesimal transformations, and then write out the matrix elements (i.e. the actual concrete numbers inside the $4 \times 4$ matrices $\Lambda$) explicitly. This will give you the second set of equations.

Comment: @Gold and why spinors needs this formalism? Why don't define spinors in terms of lorentz boosts transformations, like $(1)-(4)$, laws at first place? And why we need infinitesimal versions?

Comment: Spinors are just one specific representation of the Lorentz group. When you define the generators $\Sigma^{\alpha\beta}$ as in your equation (9) you are free to exponentiate in the representation and act with a finite Lorentz transformation $D(\Lambda)=\exp(\frac{i}{2}\omega_{\alpha\beta}\Sigma^{\alpha\beta})$. Notice that this tells you exactly how does someone act with a Lorentz transformation on them.

Comment: And to answer your question "and why we need infinitesimal versions", for starters if we have the representation, by expanding near the identity the infinitesimal versions are there anyway. Secondly, this has to do with the way we construct the representations. We most often first build representations of the algebra and then exponentiate. For Lorentz we study the representations of complexified $\mathfrak{so}(1,3)$ and find that the problem reduces to ${\frak su}(2)$ representations, which we know well (it's just good old QM angular momentum theory).